# how to create a symlink for an exīsting PVC in kubernetes pod?

Tags: kubernetes-pvc

I have mounted a volume with PVC in a POD and would like to create a symlink to this path in the POD. Please advise.

I tried to add multiple Volumes with same PVC and trying to mount it. But it's throwing errors. My expectation is should have 2 mount paths in a POD pointing to same shared nfs location.

Answer (score 1):

You can not create a Simlink as you are used from Linux within the Pod pointing on a PVC as this is potentially shared about several Pods.
But you can just mount the same PVC multiple times into several destinations or event subfolders from the PVC into a different subfolder like

```
spec:
      containers:
        - name: test
          image: test
          volumeMounts:
            - name: test_pvc
              mountPath: /home/user/path1
            - name: test_pvc
              mountPath: /home/user/path2
            - name: test_pvc
              mountPath: /home/user/path2/subfolder
              subPath: subfolder
      volumes:
        - name: test_pvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: test_pvc
```